# View log of the locations Visual Studio searches to find a dll

Tags: visual-studio

There is a Visual Studio add-in that lets you see a log of the locations that Visual Studio is searching to find dll dependencies. If I remember correctly, I believe the name of the add-in begins with the letters "fus". Does anyone know what the add-in is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)